# Setting xScale for the data in d3 js?

Tags: d3.js

I have titanic data from Kaggle.
The data looks like,

```
[{ Age: "22"
Cabin: ""
Embarked: "S"
Fare: "7.25"
Name: "Braund, Mr. Owen Harris"
Parch: "0"
PassengerId: "1"
Pclass: "3"
Sex: "male"
SibSp: "1"
Survived: "0"
Ticket: "A/5 21171"}, {...}, ...]
```

I want to draw bar chart which x-axis has male and female and y-axis has count.
The bar chart will show the number of survivor(`data[index].Survived === 1`).

My yScale is,

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var height = parseInt(svg.style('height'), 10) -20

var countValue = function(arrayData, filterValie){
    var count = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++){
        if(arrayData[i].Sex === filterValue)
        count += 1
    }
}
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, Math.max(countValue(data, 'male'), countValue(data, 'female'))])
    .range([height, 0])

var xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .domain(data.map(function (d) {return d.Sex})) // What should I have to pass as input in here
    .range(['male', 'female'])
```

So that the bar chart shows the number of survivors by its gender?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks correct but you're missing a closing bracket at the end of the domain part of xScale `.domain(data.map(function (d) {return d.Sex}))`

Comment: yeah, I fixed it.